# Why I cannot access to this page with urls.py?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I have a very simple question but I don't achieve to solve this problem :

my url is the following :

```
http://localhost:8000/myApp/activate/eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJvbWFyaWM5MSIsImFjdGlvbiI6ImFjdGl2YXRpb24ifQ:1lDysD:ZdbBiSLf0zjSWM-fpvUn_oeEG-5h6GuW4MhSkipPa38
```

And in my urls.py I define that :

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'activate/(?P<hashtag>)/', views.index),
]
```

But I got that : `Page not found (404)`

I need to catch the variable `hashtag` but I don't know why it does not work...

Could you help me please ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

The `hashtag` group in your URL regex is empty and does not match anything. You need to add something for the group to match, you could just add `.*` to make it match anything:

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'activate/(?P<hashtag>.*)/', views.index),
]
```